# Custom render RichTextBlock to remove <div class="rich-text">

Tags: django, richtextbox, wagtail

I'm sure the answer is right there and I'm not seeing it. How can I render a `RichTextBlock` to remove the wrapping `<div class="rich-text">`?

`{% include_block block %}` and `{{ block.value }}` both give the wrapping `div`.

Comment: @mohammed-qudah Please don't edit posts to add "please help" etc - the standard convention on Stack Overflow is to leave those kinds of additions out. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @gasman i improved the formatting by surrounding code with ` but stack overflow don't accept edits that change less than six characters so i added that please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is hard-coded and can't currently be overridden - see https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1214.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a custom template tag

In your project create a file in your templatetags directory (e.g. templatetags/wagtailcustom_tags.py) with content along the following.

```py
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from wagtail.core.rich_text import RichText, expand_db_html

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def richtext_withclasses(value, classes):
    if isinstance(value, RichText):
        html = expand_db_html(value.source)
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        html = expand_db_html(value)
    elif value is None:
        html = ""
    else:
        raise TypeError(
            "'richtext_withclasses' template filter received an invalid value; expected string, got {}.".format(
                type(value)
            )
        )

    return mark_safe('<div class="' + classes + '">' + html + "</div>")
```

Then in your templates load the template tag

```
{% load wagtailcustom_tags %}
```

and render richtext fields with the custom classes (or no classes at all)

```
{{ myfield | richtext_withclasses:"my custom class" }}
```